# What's the difference between q and d in git add --patch?

Tags: git

I was trying out `git add --patch` and typing ? at this prompt:

> Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]

gives me the explanation of the commands, but I can't understand the difference between these:

```
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones  
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
```

(using Git version 2.20.1)

Comment: Did you see this comment "q does not reset any previously staged changes. Whatever you have already staged remains staged" in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605405/what-does-each-of-the-y-n-q-a-d-k-j-j-g-e-stand-for-in-context-of-git-p

Comment: @lx07 Thanks! No I hadn't seen it. But from what I've seen `d` does not reset previously staged changes either..?

Comment: I don't know - "d will proceed to the next file" apparently.  I don't know the answer - just thought the comments on that question were relevant to your question and may make sense to you.  Hopefully someone better informed can add more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @lx07 mentioned in his comment, `d` will proceed to the next file while `q` will quit the whole process.